# Why won't this Django TestCase test pass?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testcase

I am trying to write tests for an API.  I'm having trouble with a couple of User model methods.  The methods all work in development and production environments, but the test does not.

Here is the test:

```
    def test_delete_user(self):
        USER_DELETED = 1

        self.u = self.setup()
        result = User.delete_user(self.u, self.u.pk)

        # response
        self.assertEqual(result, USER_DELETED)
        # functionality
        self.assertIsNone(self.u)
        print(self.u)
```

When I run this test, the return value `USER_DELETED` is correct, but the user object is not actually deleted.

`self.setup()` returns a single created user.  I can post this if it is needed, but the setup and teardown both work with various other tests in the UserTest class.

Here is the model method being tested:

```
@staticmethod
    def delete_user(requesting_user, user_id):
        # static variables
        USER_DELETED = 1
        NOT_AUTHORIZED = 0
        NO_USER = -1

        user_to_be_deleted = User.get_user_from_user_id(user_id)

        if user_to_be_deleted == NO_USER:
            return NO_USER

        # check for authorization to delete
        if requesting_user != user_to_be_deleted:
            return NOT_AUTHORIZED

        user_to_be_deleted.delete()

        return USER_DELETED
```

I also tried creating the user with the setup and then calling `self.u.delete()` instead of the custom method I have.  This gives the same result: `AssertionError: <User: test_user> is not None`

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the result the same if you call `self.u.refresh_from_db()` prior to asserting that it's `None`?

Comment: I just tried `self.u.refresh_from_db()` and it gave me this error: `prototype.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.` which makes me think that this is on the right track.

Comment: Deleting the entry from the database will not cause the instance to suddenly be `None`. You need to test that an entry no longer exists in the database with the same pk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use asserRaises to test the delete functionality. as Thomas mentioned you should `self.u.refresh_from_db`, but that will  raise `DoesNotExists` since the object is deleted, so the proper way to test  as follow.

```
def test_delete_user(self):
    USER_DELETED = 1

    self.u = self.setup()
    result = User.delete_user(self.u, self.u.pk)

    # response
    self.assertEqual(result, USER_DELETED)
    # functionality

    with self.assertRaises(User.DoesNotExist):
         self.u.refresh_from_db()
```

Comment: For more info, see the docs on this topic: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects Specifically, "This only deletes the object in the database; the Python instance will still exist and will still have data in its fields"

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using assertFalse() to see of the queryset exists when querying for the pk.  I think your solution might be a bit more straight forward though.